# How I create a LDAP Filter with City ("l") Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I wrote a Program that get Data from the Active Directory and I need a LDAP filter that filter the Data to l (city) Parameter.

My Code:

```
public void SearchByCity(string city)
        {
                                                         //What I must do :(
            DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<l= + city + >");
            string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn=*))";
            DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filter);

            var q = from s in Searcher.FindAll().OfType<SearchResult>()
                    select new
                    {
                        Benutzer = GetProperty(s, "sAMAccountName"),
                        eMail = GetProperty(s, "mail"),
                        Vorname = GetProperty(s, "givenName"),
                        Nachname = GetProperty(s, "sn"),
                        Telefon = GetProperty(s, "telephoneNumber"),
                        UserID = s.GetDirectoryEntry().Guid
                    };

            this.myListView.DataSource = q;
            this.myListView.DataBind();
        }
```

tarasov

Comment: nope l for city in the LDAP filter but I have the aolution now... I post it

Comment: string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(l=" + city + ")(cn=*))";  //city is the LDAP Parameter value

Comment: Consider the present filter component `cn=*`. This maybe not be necessary if all the candidate entries have a `CN` attribute. If that is the case, the search would be faster without the present filter.

Comment: CN is mandatory on users so you don't need to include that part of the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solition:

```
public void SearchByPlace(string city)
        {
            DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Properties.Settings.Default.Domain);
            string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(l=" + city + ")(cn=*))";
            DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filter);

            var q = from s in Searcher.FindAll().OfType<SearchResult>()
                    select new
                    {
                        Benutzer = GetProperty(s, "sAMAccountName"),
                        eMail = GetProperty(s, "mail"),
                        Vorname = GetProperty(s, "givenName"),
                        Nachname = GetProperty(s, "sn"),
                        Telefon = GetProperty(s, "telephoneNumber"),
                        UserID = s.GetDirectoryEntry().Guid
                    };

            this.myListView.DataSource = q;
            this.myListView.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this filter

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(l=yourcity))
```